# Proving that numerator of harmonic series is divisible by p

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let p be a prime number. Prove that the numerator of $1+$$1 \over 2$+ $1 \over 3$+ $\cdots$  + $1 \over p-1$ (when expressed as a single fraction) is divisible by p.

I think this may have something to do with the fact that each term here has one inverse? Not sure how to express that in math terms though.

Comment: $p$ must be an odd prime, the numerator of $\frac{1}{1}$ is not divisible by $2$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that $1+ \frac{1}{2} + \ldots + \frac{1}{p-1} = \left(1+ \frac{1}{p-1}\right) + \left(\frac{1}{2}+ \frac{1}{p-2}\right) + \ldots + \left(\frac{1}{\left\lfloor\frac{p}{2}\right\rfloor}+ \frac{1}{\left\lfloor\frac{p}{2}\right\rfloor+1}\right)$.

This evaluates to:
$$
\left(\frac{p}{p-1}\right) + \left(\frac{p}{2(p-2)}\right) + \ldots + \left(\frac{p}{\left(\left\lfloor\frac{p}{2}\right\rfloor \right)\left(\left\lfloor\frac{p}{2}\right\rfloor+1\right)}\right)
$$

The denominator is not divisible by $p$, because it is $(p-1)!$ which is not a multiple of $p$ as $p$  is prime. The numerator is clearly divisible by $p$. Hence the numerator of the reduced fraction is also divisible by $p$.

Read up Wolstemholme's theorem. It states that in fact, the numerator is divisible by $p^2$.

Comment: Can you explain the very first step pls? How does $1=1+$ $1 \over p-1$?

Comment: I just grouped together the first and last $n$th terms of the expression. Then I put each pair in brackets and took the LCM.

Comment: @DERPYPENGUIN Of course $1 \ne 1 + \frac{1}{p-1}$.  But any finite sum can be rearranged and regrouped without changing the sum.

Comment: $$S=1+\frac{1}{2}+\ldots+\frac{1}{p-2}+\frac{1}{p-1}$$
$$S=\frac{1}{p-1}+\frac{1}{p-2}+\ldots+\frac{1}{2}+1$$
$$2S=\left( 1+ \frac{1}{p-1} \right)+\left( \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{p-2} \right)+\ldots+\left( \frac{1}{p-2}+\frac{1}{2} \right) +\left( \frac{1}{p-1}+1 \right)$$

Comment: For the last term in the first line, wouldn't it be ($1 \over ⌊p/2⌋$ + $1 \over ⌊p /2⌋+1$?

Comment: @DERPYPENGUIN You are right, I have edited my answer.

Comment: Thank you, I'm very close to understanding the proof, but I just have one more question. How do you know that the denominator is equal to $(p-1)!$ ?

Comment: If $p=2$, then $$S=1$$ which fails.

If $p>2$, then
$$S=
\left( 1+ \frac{1}{p-1} \right)+\left( \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{p-2} \right)+\ldots+\left( \frac{1}{\frac{p-1}{2}}+\frac{1}{p-\frac{p-1}{2}} \right)$$

Comment: @DERPYPENGUIN Well, just multiply all the denominators, and see what you get. While adding fractions, the denominator of the result is the product of the fractions, right?

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг Guess I've been up too long. Thank you!

Comment: @DERPYPENGUIN You are welcome. Hope you have understood.

Answer (score 2):

Well, writing the harmonic series as a single factor give
\begin{align}
\sum^{p-1}_{k=1} \frac{1}{k} = \sum^{p-1}_{k=1} \frac{1\cdot 2\cdots \hat k \cdots (p-1)}{(p-1)!} =:\sum^{p-1}_{k=1} \frac{a_k}{(p-1)!} \ \ \ \ (*)
\end{align}
where $\hat k$ indicates the missing multiple. Using Wilson's theorem which states
\begin{align}
ka_k=(p-1)! \equiv -1 \mod p \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ a_k \equiv -k^{-1} \mod p
\end{align}
which means
\begin{align}
\sum^{p-1}_{k=1} a_k \equiv -\sum^{p-1}_{k=1} k^{-1}  \mod p.
\end{align}
Essentially, we are summing over units in $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ which is zero since
\begin{align}
1+2+\ldots +(p-1) = \frac{p(p-1)}{2}.
\end{align}

Note: It should be noted that the denominator of $(*)$ is not divisible by $p$ which means it will not cancel out the $p$ in the numerator when you look at the reduced fraction of $(*)$.

Comment: The numerator of the reduced fraction is not necessarily given by $\sum a_k$. But since the denominator $(p-1)!$ of the non-reduced fraction isn't divisible by $p$, the factor $p$ in the numerator of $\dfrac{\sum a_k}{(p-1)!}$ can't be cancelled, hence remains in the numerator of the reduced fraction.

Comment: @DanielFischer So is my proof incorrect? I know for a fact that $1+1/2+\ldots + 1/(p-1)$ can not be an integer. Therefore, when the question asks to show that the numerator is divisible by $p$ then I just work with the numerator.

Comment: It has a (small) hole. You correctly prove that $\sum a_k$ is divisible by $p$. But in $$\sum_{k = 1}^{p-1} \frac{1}{k} = \frac{\sum_{k = 1}^{p-1} a_k}{(p-1)!},$$ the right hand side is not always a reduced fraction (the case $p = 5$ is a small example). So you need to give an argument that the factor $p$ cannot be cancelled from the numerator when reducing the right hand side. That follows from the fact that $p$ doesn't divide the denominator of the right hand side.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thanks. I have updated my post.

Comment: @JackyChong how "we are summing over units.." from what preceeded?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the simplest approach is the following, also given by Jacky Chong:

Rewrite the terms from $1$ to $1/(1-p) $ with the denominator $ (1-p)! $, the kth term being 
$ (p-1)!/k(p-1)! $

If $ (p-1)!/a(p-1)! = (p-1)!/b(p-1)! $ then we must have a=b.  Therefore the denominators constitute $p-1$ different numbers (mod p) from $1$ to $p-1$, none of which is $0$ (mod p), and the same is true for the nominators.

Therefore the same is trues for the terms $ (p-1)!/k(p-1)! $. They constitute a permutation of the numbers 1 to p-1 (mod p).

Therefore their sum is (from the arithmetic series formula) $p(p-1)/2$ (mod  p) , that is $= 0$ (mod p). It doesn't show that the sum is also $0$ (mod $p^2$)