# Answer without using mod Let $\frac{a}{b}=1+\frac{1}{2}+... +\frac{1}{p-2}$. Show that $a-b$ is divisible by $p$.

Tags: prime-numbers, divisibility, fractions

**PROBLEM**

Let the natural numbers $a,b,p$ be non-zero, and $p$ be an odd prime number, so that the relation $\frac{a}{b}=1+\frac{1}{2}+... +\frac{1}{p-2}$. Show that $a-b$ is divisible by $p$.

**WHAT I THOUGHT OF**

I think that the formula $\frac{y-x}{x*y}=\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{x}$ as we can rewrite the second part to fit. I don't know what else to do or how to start solving it! Hope one of you can help me!

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1953161/proving-that-numerator-of-harmonic-series-is-divisible-by-p

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thank you, but I still don't really understand.

Comment: "I don't understand" is not helpful. What exactly don't you understand? At which point of the explanations do you get stuck?

Comment: @GerryMyerson The problem is till $p-1$, mine is till $p-2$. That makes a lot of changes. Also I have to show that $a-b$ is divisible by $p$

Comment: @GerryMyerson Nevermind, i understood. But i still have a last question... why $\left(\frac{1}{\left\lfloor\frac{p}{2}\right\rfloor}+ \frac{1}{\left\lfloor\frac{p}{2}\right\rfloor+1}\right)$. can be written as $\left(\frac{p}{\left(\left\lfloor\frac{p}{2}\right\rfloor \right)\left(\left\lfloor\frac{p}{2}\right\rfloor+1\right)}\right)$

Comment: Do you see why, if $p$ is odd, then $[p/2]=(p-1)/2$?

Comment: I agree with OP that this is not really a duplicate. The linked question is similar and can be solved with a similar approach, but it is not immediately obvious how to translate either result into the other.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Oooo...now i understand! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interpret everything modulo $p$. First of all, we have
$$
1^{-1} + 2^{-1} + \ldots + (p-1)^{-1} = 1 + 2 + \ldots + (p-1) = \frac{p-1}{2} \cdot p \equiv 0 \mod p.
$$
Because $(p-1)^{-1} = -1$, it follows that
$$
1^{-1} + 2^{-1} + \ldots + (p-2)^{-1} \equiv 1 \mod p,
$$
and we obtain $a \equiv b \mod p$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I just want to ask why you eliminated the power of $-1$.

Comment: And another thing: the sum ends with $p-2$, not $p-1$

Comment: Each one of $1$, $2$, ..., $p-1$ has a unique inverse modulo $p$. Therefore, $1^{-1}$, ..., $(p-1)^{-1}$ is a permutation of $1$, $2$, ..., $(p-1)$.

Comment: @user133281 Very nice illustration.

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).

Answer (score 1):

The cyclic group $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}-\{ 0 \}$ is generated by element $a$. Now $1+\frac{1}{2}+…+\frac{1}{p-2}=\frac{N}{(p-2)!}$ where $N=(p-2)!+\frac{(p-2)!}{2}+…+\frac{(p-2)!}{p-2}$. From $a(p-2)!=bN$ we have $a=bN$ mod $p$. We only need to prove that $N=1$ mod $p$.
Now $N-1=\sum_{0 \leq j \leq p-2, j \neq \frac{p-1}{2}}a^{-j}-1=\sum_{0 \leq j \leq p-2, j \neq \frac{p-1}{2}}a^{j}+a^{\frac{p-1}{2}}=\sum_{0 \leq j \leq p-2}a^{j}=0$ mod $p$. Therefore we have proven the statement.

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).

Answer (score 1):

Because of the unicity of inverses there is bijection between the inverses and the elements  in $\mathbb F_p$ therefore
$$1^{-1} + 2^{-1} + \ldots + (p-2)^{-1}+(p-1)^{-1}=1+2+\cdots+(p-2)+(p-1)=0$$ which implies $$\frac ab=-(p-1)\equiv 1\pmod p\iff a-b\equiv 0\pmod p$$
We are done.

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).